# Should questions be asked to adherents of specific denominations?

Tags: discussion

This question, like very many others, asks for an answer from persons who hold particular beliefs.

[This question is for the Jehovah's Witnesses? They teach Jesus Christ is "a god," so how is it that all the fullness of deity dwells in Him?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/97270/this-question-is-for-the-jehovahs-witnesses-they-teach-jesus-christ-is-a-god)

It seems to me the beliefs of a person answering the question are irrelevant and the question should be answerable by anyone, regardless of belief.

I completely understand and agree that a question is seeking the views of a paricular denomination. But a knowledge of, and expertise in, a particular denominations beliefs is not necessarily confined to its adherents.

So rather than saying this question is **for** the Jehovah's Witnesses, would it be more appropriate to say this question is **about** the Jehovah's Witnesses?

Provided appropriate links and references are given, the personal beliefs of the answerer ought not to matter?

Comment: It’s not necessary that answerer be adherents of the denomination. Frequently the answerer are not adherents but have researched the denomination in question and can thus give a supported answer.  I

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if the question says "this question is for the Jehovah's Witnesses" we still understand it to mean "this question is about the beliefs of Jehovah's Witnesses".  It's definitely OK to edit to make the meaning clearer, but it's not a reason to close the question as off topic since the subject of the site is not particular Jehovah's Witnesses who use the site, but the teachings of that sect.

Answer (score 2):

Questions are not and should not be asked "to" specific people, like adherents of a specific denomination.  Instead, questions should be asked *about* the beliefs of specific denominations.  Anyone with knowledge is free to answer.

If you see a question that is phrased as being "to" specific people, feel free to edit it to change the wording.

Also, on Stack Exchange, the title should contain a short summary, not the full question.  If the title is two sentences / two questions, then that's not following the Stack Exchange format.  The question itself belongs in the body of the post, not the title.  We're not Quora.  Feel free to edit any post you see that deviates from this expectation.